# Opening/Writing to a file from a KProbe handler

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I am writing a Linux kernel module using Kprobes to trace specific system calls, and I need to write to a file from within a KProbe handler (specifically, a Kretprobe). I know this is generally not advised, but I need to write the output to a very specific location, so I can't use any standard logging mechanisms.

I can open/write fine from the init() function in the module, but when I try to do so from within a probe handler, the kernel crashes.

Comment: Could you show the code or the portions of it? Generally, one should not do heavy operations in Kprobe handlers (preemption and local interrupts are disabled, etc.). May be, use a workqueue to execute these file operations in a less restricted environment?